# Best practice for passing :user_id into params for a new object from a nested resource form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

```
# User model
has_many :forums
has_many :posts

# Forum model
belongs_to :user
has_many :posts

# Post model
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :forum
```

I have a `post` form that is nested in a `forum`. I want to initialize the form with the needed `forum_id` and `user_id` so it can be save correctly at the end.

This is my (failing) attempt.

```
# posts_controller
def new
  @post = current_user.forums.find(params[:forum_id]).posts.new
end
```

This is what @post gets me as a result:

```
# @post
#<Post id: nil, title: nil, description: nil, user_id: nil, forum_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Perhaps I'm not doing this correctly at all. I'd like to find the best practice or just a one of the better options than forcing things.

Would it be better to bring in the `user_id` all the way through the form until it's creation?

Is there a better way that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `build`:

```
@post = Forum.find(params[:forum_id]).posts.build
```

Comment: When I use that on the new action it builds `@post` with a `forum_id`. However, when it reaches create, the `forum_id` has been stripped and becomes `nil`. my `post_params` has `:forum_id` and `:user_id` has been whitelisted. Does this sound normal do you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
@post = Post.new(user_id: current_user.id, forum_id: params[:forum_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set user_id separately, as it won't be set by `forum.posts.new`

```
forum = current_user.forums.find(params[:forum_id])
@post = forum.posts.new(user_id: current_user.id)
```